# Do I have to use join?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Table A

```
id_a int pr
name text
```

Table B

```
id_a int FR
age int
```

I want to execute something a query something like this

```
Select id_a,name,age from A,B where A.id_a=B.id_a;
```

I have tried joins but no progress Where am I making a mistake

Answer (score 1):

Use explicit joins, and qualify the columns so they are unambiguous.

So:

```
select a.id_a, a.name, b.age 
from a
inner join b on a.id_a = b.id_a;
```

Since the joining columns have the same name, you can also use `USING()`, which disambiguate the joining column:

```
select id_a, a.name, b.age 
from a
inner join b using (id_a)
```